# HTML/CSS elements don't looks precisely in needed position

Tags: html, css

Made custom checkbox styles. But in different viewport widths dots inside of circles looks in a different position.

[image]   [image]

This is how it looks in one viewport width and another image shows how it looks in another viewport. In all cases, the radius of elements doesn't change. Here you can see the code that I use for the WordPress website.

Is there some way to make dots stable in any viewports?

```css
input {
    &[type="radio"] {
        &:checked, &:not(:checked) {
            position: absolute;
            left: -9999px;

            & + label {
                position: relative;
                padding-left: 28px;
                cursor: pointer;
                line-height: 20px;
                display: inline-block;
                color: #666;

                &::before {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 16px;
                    height: 16px;
                    border: 1px solid rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.5);
                    border-radius: 100%;
                    background: #fff;
                }
                &::after {
                    content: '';
                    width: 10px;
                    height: 10px;
                    background: $theme_color;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 3px;
                    left: 3px;
                    border-radius: 100%;
                    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
                    transition: all 0.2s ease;
                }
            }
        }
        &:not(:checked) {
            & + label {
                &::after {
                    opacity: 0;
                    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
                    transform: scale(0);
                }
            }
        }
        &:checked {
            & + label {
                &::after {
                    opacity: 1;
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                    transform: scale(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
    <label for="test1">Apple</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test2">Peach</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test3">Orange</label>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: can you check if this works correctly: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/NWapxBN?

Answer (score 2):

Add **`display: flex`** to the `<p>` elements to prevent the label text wrapping below the radio button.

```css
p{
    display: flex;
}
form{
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
            <label for="test1">Apple</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
            <label for="test2">This is some long piece of text that might wrap on smaller devices</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
            <label for="test3">Orange</label>
        </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: i agree, but it has nothing to with his question

Comment: This HTML code I added for instance. In my WP website there is `li` tag. I applied for `li` these properties: `display: flex; align-items: center;`, also aligned `:before` and `:after` elements to center. Result is the same. Dots inside of circles position changes when change viewport, but only in 2px limits.